# If an element in ring of integers is square modulo every prime, then it is a square in ring of integers.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I know that if an integer is square modulo every integer prime, then it is an integer square.

I was investigating if same holds in any algebraic number field 'L = $\mathbb{Q}$ [ a$_{1}$, ... , a$_{k}$ ] i.e. if $\alpha$ is in ring of integers 'O' and $\alpha$ is square modulo every prime 'p' in ring of integers, then $\alpha$ is actually a square in ring of integers.

Does this hold at least when k = 1 and extension is quadratic ?

I took a course in algebraic-number-theory but hardly remember any of it. Could someone please help me?

Comment: You  want to learn about [the Grunwald-Wang theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grunwald%E2%80%93Wang_theorem). BY Hensel 's lemma, a square root modulo a prime ideal $\mathfrak{p}$ can be lifted to square root in the $\mathfrak{p}$-adic completion unless $2\equiv0\pmod{\mathfrak{p}}$ or the square root itself is not a $\mathfrak{p}$-adic unit. I think these conditions only rule out finitely many prime ideals, so... Do check, I'm a bit rusty at this.

Comment: I believe this follows from a theorem due to Dedekind and Kummer, which relates the splitting of a prime $\mathfrak{p}$ in a separable extension to the splitting modulo $\mathfrak{p}$ of the minimal polynomial of a generator of the extension, together with the Chebotarev density theorem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me expand Ethan Alwaise's comment into an answer.

Let $L$ be a number field and $\alpha\in \mathcal O_L$ be a square modulo every prime. Suppose by contradiction that $\alpha$ is not a square. Then the polynomial $x^2-\alpha$ is irreducible in $L[x]$. Hence, the field extension $L(\sqrt{\alpha})/L$ has degree 2. This implies that the Galois group of such extension is $C_2$. Hence, by Chebotarev there exist infinitely many primes of $L$ that are inert in $L(\sqrt{\alpha})$. Choose one of these primes $p$ large enough. Then by Dedekind-Kummer the splitting of $p$ in $L(\sqrt{\alpha})$ is governed by the factorization of $x^2-\alpha$ modulo $p$. But this is a product of two linear factors by hypothesis, leading to a contradiction.

Comment: Also we can avoid Chebotarev : in such situation up to finitely many ramified primes $\zeta_{L(\sqrt{\alpha})}(s) =\zeta_L(s)^2$, following elementary methods showing $\zeta_k(s)\sim C_k/(s-1)$ as $s\to 1^+$  this is a contradiction.

Comment: Ferra@ Thank you so much. Somehow looking at your answer (which is so clear in thought process) inspired me on my other problems too. Just one question bothering me, why do we need to take 'p' large enough?

Comment: cause in order to apply Dedekind-Kummer at $p$ you must have that $p\nmid [\mathcal O_{L(\alpha)}:\mathcal O_L[\alpha]]$, which happens for all but finitely many primes.